# Degenerate eigenvalues and finding normalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvalues and the normalized eigenvectors of the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & i & 0\\0 & 0& i\\i & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

It is stated that the eigenvalues are : $\lambda_1 = i\omega$, $\lambda_2 = i$ and $\lambda_3 = i\omega^2$
and two of the normalised eigenvectors are:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega^2\\\omega\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm not sure what $\omega$ means in this case and how to arrive to this result, given that $i$ is a degenerate eigenvalue.

Comment: I suspect that $\omega$ has been used in this way previously in your study materials.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix is equal to $iM$, where$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Therefore, its eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of $M$ times $i$. But the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $1-x^3$ and therefore its eigenvalues are $\{1,\omega,\omega^2\}$, where$$\omega=-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$

Answer (score 0):

$\omega$ is used for a lot of different things in math, but in this context it's generally used to represent a non-principal cube root of $1$. That is, $\omega$ is a number such that $\omega^3=1$ but $\omega \neq 1$. While there are two numbers that satisfy that relation, they are conjugates of each other and thus indistinguishable by polynomials over the reals. (Taking different values to be $\omega$ will result in the expressions you have evaluating to the same set of eigenvalues, albeit in a different order.) If a particular number is needed, it's generally taken to be the first one, going counter-clockwise, from $1$ in the complex plane, i.e. -$\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$.

$i$ is not degenerate; $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is the only (up to scaling) eigenvalue for that eigenvalue. Both its arithmetic and geometric multiplicities are $1$.

Comment: Another usual notation is $j$.

Answer (score 0):

Here a direct calculation.

The characteristic polynomial of our matrix 
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i \\
i & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
is given by
\begin{align*}
\chi_A(t)
&= \det(t\cdot I_3-A) \\
&= \left|\begin{array}{rrr}
t & -i & 0 \\
0 & t & -i \\
-i & 0 & t
\end{array}\right| \\
&\overset{\ast}{=}\left|\begin{array}{rrr}
t - i & t - i & t - i \\
0 & t & -i \\
-i & 0 & t
\end{array}\right| \\
&= (t-i)\left|\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & t & -i \\
-i & 0 & t
\end{array}\right| \\
&\overset{\circledast}{=}(t-i)\left|\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & t & -i \\
0 & i & t + i
\end{array}\right| \\
&= (t-i)\left|\begin{array}{rr}
t & -i \\
i & t + i
\end{array}\right| \\
&= (t-i)\cdot\{t^2+i\,t+i^2\} \\
&=(t-i)\cdot\{t^2+i\,t-1\} \\
&\overset{q}{=} (t-i)\cdot\left(t-\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\cdot \left(t-\frac{-i-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
The equality marked $\ast$ is obtained by replacing row one with the sum of all three rows of the previous matrix. The equality marked $\circledast$ is obtained by adding $i$ times row one to row three. The equality marked $q$ is obtained from the quadratic formula.

Our factorization of $\chi_A(t)$ shows that the eigenvalues of $A$ are
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &= i & \lambda_2 &= \frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{2} & \lambda_3 &= \frac{-i-\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}